# How to count a total in Postgresql and not have a range for each row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

On our postgreSql Database we have two table one is appointment and the other one location. We are currently counting the number of Appointment per location.

We use the following query. Unfortunately it is giving one row per every appointment whereas we would like to count the total. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

```
select "domain".locations."name" AS  "Location Name",
       COUNT("domain".appointments."id") AS "Number Of Appointment",
       "domain".locations.mongo AS "Location ID Mongo",
       "domain".locations."id" AS "Location ID",
       "domain".countries."name" AS "Country Name",
       to_char("domain".appointments.created_at,'FMDD.MM.YYYY') AS "Appointment Created Date"
from "domain".appointments
INNER JOIN "domain".locations
    ON  "domain".locations."id" = "domain".appointments.location_id
INNER JOIN "domain".countries
    ON "domain".locations.country_id = "domain".countries."id"
WHERE "domain".appointments."source" = 'extranet'
  AND date_trunc('day', "domain".appointments.created_at) = date_trunc('day', current_date - 1)
  AND "domain".locations."id" <> '2016'
GROUP BY "domain".locations."id",
         "domain".locations."name",
         "domain".countries."name",
         "domain".appointments.created_at,
         "domain".appointments."id"
```

Comment: Tip of today: table aliases!

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the presentation of the code, how did you do to present it so well? Is there some process to follow on Stack overflow? Thank you!

Comment: When editing, mark the SQL code and click the `{}` symbol.

Comment: Jarlh I was just finally able to use the table aliases, so practical! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Have fun with SQL!